# SWI Prolog syntax need to write more than one word in term

Tags: prolog

How can I write more than one word in hypothesize term and other side? For example I want to write `small cat`

```
hypothesize(cat) :- cat, !.
```

I tried to write it with underscore but in the result the underscore appear which I don't want.

This is the full code.

[https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_17.html](https://www.cpp.edu/%7Ejrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_17.html)

Answer (score 1):

Besides underscores (`small_cat`) you can also write multi-word atoms with single quotes: `'small cat'`.

For example:

```
?- Cat = 'small cat'.
Cat = 'small cat'.
```

Maybe you don't want the quotes in the output. In this case, the good news is that if you use `write` for printing your answer, like the code you linked, the quotes will not be printed:

```
?- write('small cat').
small cat
true.
```

If you do want quotes when writing such atoms, you can use `writeq` ("write quoted"):

```
?- writeq('small cat').
'small cat'
true.
```